# Python/Pandas: Create 1x1 Dataframe Containing a Single String

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Quick question, I need to create a new dataframe that contains only a single a string.
Why I hear you ask? Great question! I will explain...

So, after a bit of searching over the past couple weeks I have found that the only effective method of pushing new dataframes to an existing xlsx (template) file (without overwriting or destroying cell formulae) is to use openpyxl (with a helper function). With that understood, I need to be able to push a single string to the xlsx workbook without destroying the data loaded into it earlier in the script. The easiest method that came to mind was creating single 1x1 dataframes containing the strings and push that into the workbook using the method elluded to earlier.

Please let me know if there is a simple way to achieve this, or an alternative using openpyxl. Or some other alternative. I know that the method I am purposing is not at all elegant, and is probably a great example of improper use of dataframes (obviously not designed for handling single instances, but rather is for larger structures).

Anyway, enough rambling. Hopefully you all understand what I am attempting. If not, please respond and I can clarify (response times may be slow as I am travelling).

Comment: Interesting, what about empty DataFrame like pd.DataFrame() ? Would that work also ?  If not, then pd.DataFrame(['Hi']) ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it wouldn't create the dataframe, just kept erroring saying: "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify excel file with openpyxl without Pandas:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = 'data.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws['C4'] = 9
wb.save(filename)
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Note the cells in row 5 contain a formula which is not replaced by the values.

Comment: Yeah, this works perfectly. And avoids the use of dataframes. Thank you @Corralien